# Get value from select statement in php

Tags: php, sql

```
if (isset($_POST['submitProf'])){
if (isset($_POST['address'])) {
    $address = $_POST['address'];

    if (!empty($address)) {
        $query = "SELECT `username` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'";
        $query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($query_run) == 1){
                $query_username = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($query_run,1);
                 $query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`Address`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$address)."') WHERE `username` = '$query_username'";
                    if ($query_run = mysqli_query($connection,$query)) {
                          echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Updated')</script>";
                     }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have a submit button, when its pressed I want to update the address column in my database for the user who is logged in.
The first select statement is to check wether the user exists. 
But how do I take his username in a variable so that I can specify in my INSERT INTO statement in the WHERE clause the correct user. 
I tried it with fetch field direct but this doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: There is no `insert into ... Where`Syntax in SQL. What you are looking for is `UPDATE SET .. WHERE`

Comment: BTW: Learn about prepared statements

Comment: you know insert does not support a where clause right? You mean you want to update the table?

Comment: And : '$query_username' the Single Quotes prevent your Variable to be parsed

Comment: @Ann No. The single quotes is for the SQL-Statement and are correct

Comment: @Jens k... i'm used to Doctrine and Prepared Statements so it's a long time since i saw code like this ^^

Comment: @Ann prepared statments is definitivly the better way

Comment: mysqli_real_escape_string is not all that safe though ;)

Comment: I need to take a break, such a stupid mistake lol. Thx for the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert have not where clause  so should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users`(`Address`) 
    VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$address)."')";
```

but could be you need  an update

```
$query = "Update `users`
          set `Address` = '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$address)."'
         WHERE `username` = '$query_username'";
```